# User not logged out after invalidating session

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, el

Give me some suggestion instead of using scriptlets in jsp

I clicked on logout it works and says logout successfully
but without inserting username and password when I clicked on sign in, it automatically login how to solve this?

```js
<html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
     <title>logout Page</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor ="#61b3de">
     <%     
         session.removeAttribute("userId");
         session.removeAttribute("password");
         session.invalidate();
     %>
<center>
     <h1>You have successfully logged out</h1>
     To login again <a href="login.jsp">click here</a>.
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wright now learn jstl

Comment: title & body both are completely different from each other. What is ur actual question?body content is not pointing whatever u have mentioned in the title.

Comment: if u want my complete code here   http://www.javawebtutor.com/articles/hibernate/mvc-appliction-using-servlet-jsp-and-hibernate.html

Comment: How do you check for if user is authenticated or not??

Comment: first of all all of code is in above link  tell me how to implement authentication if its helpful to develop validation  then i will use

Answer (score 0):

By looking at those code provided by the link you can check if you have both user name and password in the session or not. If you do not find them then in session take the user to error page.

something like this.

```
if(session.getAttribite("userid") == null || session.getAttribite("password")==null){
    response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: i will try this in s e r v  let